# How do I add month number to a hard coded column value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a hard coded value in my SQL database and I'd like to add the month number to the value.  Here's what it looks like now:

```
SELECT 'Campaign_Reviews' as [Campaign Name]
```

And what I would like is for the **value to include the month number**: i.e.

```
Select 'Campaign_Reviews_MONTH(GETDATE())' as [Campaign Name]
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as:

```
Select 'Campaign_Reviews_' + right('00' + cast(month(GETDATE()) as varchar(255)), 2) as [Campaign Name]
```

This zero pads the number, so you get "01" rather than just "1".  The values will sort correctly.

Comment: I don't think that op actually wants the string `MONTH`  though

Answer (score 1):

If 2012+, you can use `concat()`

**Example**

```
Select concat('Campaign_Reviews_',month(GetDate())) as [Campaign Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate that value:

```
SELECT 'Campaign_Reviews_' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) [Campaign Name];
```